# Diagonal Subspace of Cartesian Product

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. If $\Delta = \{(\textbf{v},\textbf{v})| \textbf{v} \in V\}$ is the diagonal subspace of $V\times V$, show that dim$\Delta$ = dim$V$.

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem at all. Can someone push me in the right direction please?

Comment: Find a basis...

Comment: @user658409 How can I do that if I don't have what the specific subspace is? Sorry, maybe I haven't learned that, but in my past experience, I have only been asked to find bases for vector spaces for which I knew specifics. As I said in the statement of this question, I'm pretty much lost on this question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Consider the map $\;f:V\longrightarrow V\times V,\enspace b\longmapsto (v,v)$ and check it is an injective linear map.